# Consolidate spring boot micro services under swagger

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, microservices

I have started creating a project using springboot. There are multiple micro modules each having different controller. How can I expose all the controllers on a single host,port combinations. Also How can I make swagger to list all apis across different controllers.

`The project is like 
ABCD\
  --\A\A Controller
  --\A\build.gradle
  --\B\B Controller
  --\B\build.gradle 
  --build.gradle`

Thanks for any pointers.

Is there a way I can make a collective war having all the controllers inside it

I am using springfox.io for the same. The challenge is I can get all the api listed in springfox/swagger provided if I jar all the modules and add to the modules with springfox config. But for this I have to create separate module and everything is running on one server.  I want A controller to be running in one tomcat and B in another, and springfox on either C or any of A or B, but listing all apis of A and B. There might me some use case I am missing, please let me know.

Comment: To see Swagger used for Spring Boot, you could always just grab jHipster, which creates the scaffolding for Spring Boot web apps and uses Swagger for the generated API documentation: https://jhipster.github.io/

Comment: Could you provide some more detail on your application configuration? for .e.g are you using http://springfox.io? Its very straight forward to use spring-fox to group your controllers.